# How do I avoid make to generate and install man pages?

Tags: make, cygwin, configure

Context: I'm compiling OpenLDAP on Windows inside CygWin.

As I'm not interested in man pages (and possibly other documentation, I'm focused on getting the compilation done), since I can get them online, how can I tell configure and or make to skip thei generation (or at least their installation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you run `./configure`, edit `Makefile.in` in the project root to drop `doc` from the `SUBDIRS` variable. That will cause everything in the `doc` subdirectory to be ignored during the build and during installation.

```
sed -i '/SUBDIRS/s/doc//' Makefile.in
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the make file, you should see a series of rules, being lines without whitespace at the beginning. The rule you probably are used to using is `install` which usually put at the bottom of the make file, but there are usually many other rules. Look for a rule that refers to the man page source files (they usually have a single digit file extension) or some documentation directory. Once you find it, you have three options: 1) make it a null rule by removing its commands (ie. the lines after it that begin with whitespace), or 2) remove references to it, (ie. look in the other rules for commands with the name of that rule, or 3) find an already-existing install rule that doesn't perform it.

Let me give you an example, using an excerpt from a real makefile:

```
default: all

all: lisp info

info:
    cd doc && $(MAKE) EMACS="$(EMACS)"

install: install-lisp install-info

install-lisp: lisp
    @$(SHELL) $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs "$(DESTDIR)$(lispdir)";\

install-info: info
    @echo "cd doc && $(MAKE) EMACS=\"$(EMACS)\" 

dist: Makefile foo.elc
    $(MAKE) tarball \

clean:
    -rm -rf $(PACKAGE)* ;\

distclean: clean
    -rm -f config.log config.status config.cache Makefile
```

In the above example, you could either remove the line after `info:` and `install-info:` thus making it a null rule or, the better method, remove the word `install-info` from the `install` rule (the line beginning `install:`)

Now, for the third (best) option, take a second look at my example file and notice that there exists a command `install-lisp`, which you can see does everything except for installing the documentation because those are the only two commands in the `install` command. So in this example, there really is no need to change anything, just instead of running `make install` run `make install-lisp`. Your make file may give you a similar option. Without examining it, it's impossible to know.

Finally, what if you don't want to perform a `make install`? Maybe you just want to perform a vanilla `make`. For that, look for a rule called `default`; that will be the rule used when calling `make` without a specific command. In my example, you see that the `default` rule just points to another rule called `all`, and that rule calls two other rules: `lisp` and `info`. When I pasted the example, I cut most of the lines for brevity, so the text of the `lisp` rule isn't here, but it should be obvious that you do want to use that command, and not the `info` command, so you could just run `make lisp`.